# Maximize CSS table-cell width

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

On my website I have a CSS table with two table cells.
One is 400px wide, and I want the other one to take up the rest of the page.
How do I do that? I have tried applying width 100% to it, but that doesn't work on chrome, and width: auto doesn't work at all.

```
.wrapper{
    display: table;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
[...]
.sidebar{
    display: table-cell;
    border-right: 1px solid #707070;
    width: 400px;
}
[...]
.content{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Stuff -->
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Titles and text, all that usual blog stuff. Oh, and a big, wide header. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your wrapper to be display:table and not display:table-cell because otherwise the wrapper gets an anonymous table wrapper at auto width (shrink to fit for tables).

```
.wrapper{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

I wouldn't use vw for the width either as that includes the scrolbar and will cause a horizontal scrollbar when content is below the fold.

Comment: Oops, the table-cell in the wrapper was a typo, sorry for that. The width: 100% seems to be the solution, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Apply `style="width:100%"` to the `table` element, keeping the 400px limit on the first cell. The second cell will expand to meet the table's width.

Answer (score 0):

The table should automatically scale to full width (assuming it's width is 100%), even with one column fixed and the other(s) flexible. I threw up a little test/example @ http://jsfiddle.net/41uc6Lsq/1/

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="20px">Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="20px">1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: just saw your CSS edit - could you post the HTML too please?